# Programmatically set navigation settings in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

When Going to Site settings>Navigation for a subsite i want to modify The Structural Navigation:Sorting
to be the first value (Sort automatically)

I am trying to do this with my code:

```
ClientContext clientContext;
var navigation = new ClientPortalNavigation(clientContext.Web);
navigation.CurrentIncludePages = true;
navigation.GlobalIncludePages = false;
navigation.OrderingMethod = OrderingMethod.Automatic; // Settings
navigation.SaveChanges();
```

I have my code in a button so when pressing the button I want to set it to be automatic

I have also create a class by the name ClientPortalNavigation.cs
My cs file looks like this,

```
public class ClientPortalNavigation
{
public ClientPortalNavigation(Web web)
{
    _web = web;
}

#region CRUD operations

private void EnsureLoaded()
{
    if (!_web.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("AllProperties"))
    {
        Context.Load(_web, w => w.AllProperties);
        Context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}


public void SaveChanges()
{
    _web.Update();
    Context.ExecuteQuery();
}
public bool GlobalIncludePages
{
    get
    {
        return (GlobalIncludeTypes & NodeTypes.Page) == NodeTypes.Page;
    }
    set
    {
        GlobalIncludeTypes = !value ? GlobalIncludeTypes & ~NodeTypes.Page : GlobalIncludeTypes | NodeTypes.Page;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Controls whether publishing pages in this site will be automatically included in current navigation.
/// </summary>
public bool CurrentIncludePages
{
    get
    {
        return (CurrentIncludeTypes & NodeTypes.Page) == NodeTypes.Page;
    }
    set
    {
        CurrentIncludeTypes = !value ? CurrentIncludeTypes & ~NodeTypes.Page : CurrentIncludeTypes | NodeTypes.Page;
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Options that specify how navigation items are ordered.
/// </summary>
public enum OrderingMethod
{
Automatic,
ManualWithAutomaticPageSorting,
Manual,
}
/// <summary>
/// Controls the ordering of navigation items owned by this site.
/// </summary>
public OrderingMethod OrderingMethod
{
    get
    {
        return (OrderingMethod)GetProperty("__NavigationOrderingMethod", 2);
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty("__NavigationOrderingMethod", (int)value);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are using the [ClientPortalNavigation.cs class](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347) for managing navigation settings using SharePoint CSOM.

> Disclaimer: i'm the author of this class

The following examples demonstrate how to set *Structural Navigation* options.

### Example 1

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
     var navigation = new ClientPortalNavigation(ctx.Web);
     navigation.OrderingMethod = OrderingMethod.Automatic;
     navigation.SaveChanges();           
}
```

Result

[image]

### Example 2

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
     var navigation = new ClientPortalNavigation(ctx.Web);
     navigation.OrderingMethod = OrderingMethod.Automatic;
     navigation.AutomaticSortingMethod = AutomaticSortingMethod.LastModifiedDate;
     navigation.SaveChanges();           
}
```

Result

[image]

### Example 3

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
     var navigation = new ClientPortalNavigation(ctx.Web);
     navigation.OrderingMethod = OrderingMethod.Automatic;
     navigation.AutomaticSortingMethod = AutomaticSortingMethod.LastModifiedDate;
     navigation.SortAscending = false;
     navigation.SaveChanges();           
}
```

Result

[image]